# How to validate required fields in class properties?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I wanted a simple way to ensure that some properties in a class contained values and/or were within a range (ie: not more than 50 characters long). I used the question and answer on [How to validate Class properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027865/how-to-validate-class-properties) unfortunately I was not able to get it to work.

To test it, I created a very simple WinForm example using C#. Even though I am doing everything the same, it never throws a validation exception when I apply incorrect values (ie: setting the age above the allowed limit).

Can someone explain why it does not throw the exception? It's as if the class doesn't know it is supposed to use the required attributes.

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RequiredFieldsInClassExample {
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        try {
            lstStatus.Items.Clear();
            lstStatus.Items.Add("Creating list of people");
            List<Person> CollectionOfPeople = new List<Person>();

            lstStatus.Items.Add("Creating a good person");
            Person Jeff = new Person();
            Jeff.Age = 33;
            Jeff.Firstname = "Jeff";
            Jeff.Lastname = "Jefferson";
            Jeff.GroupCode = "JJJ";

            CollectionOfPeople.Add(Jeff);

            lstStatus.Items.Add("Creating a bad person");
            Person Tim = new Person();
            Tim.Age = 444;
            Tim.Firstname = "";
            Tim.Lastname = "";
            Tim.GroupCode = "";

            CollectionOfPeople.Add(Tim);

            lstStatus.Items.Add("Done");
        } catch (ValidationException Exp) {
            MessageBox.Show(this, Exp.Message, "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        } catch (Exception Exp) {
            MessageBox.Show(this, Exp.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Person.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Person {
private int m_iAge = 1;
private string m_sFirstname = "Unknown";
private string m_sLastname = "";
private string m_sGroupCode = "AAA";

//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Age is a required field.")]
//[Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "A persons age must be between 1 and 100.")]
[Required, Range(1, 100)]
public int Age
{
    get { return m_iAge; }
    set { m_iAge = value; }
}

//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Firstname is a required field.")]
[Required]
public string Firstname
{
    get { return m_sFirstname; }
    set { m_sFirstname = value; }
}

public string Lastname
{
    get { return m_sLastname; }
    set { m_sLastname = value; }
}

//[StringLength(3)]
public string GroupCode
{
    get { return m_sGroupCode; }
    set { m_sGroupCode = value; }
}
}
```

Comment: It's not going to validate properties upon setting values, you have to [trigger validation manually](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx).

Comment: @Michael - Can you create an answer, since your link contained the information that allowed me to solve the problem?

Comment: You can also post your own answer and self-accept it after a delay, if no other answers suffice.  This will mark the question as answered which will help future readers.

Comment: ThePeter I would follow @Tim's advise... Since you solved your problem I would suggest to post it and self-accept it... It might help someone else in the future...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a new method into the Person class to perform the validation. The new "Validate" method works for required values, range, and string length.

**Person.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text;

public class Person {
private int m_iAge = 1;
private string m_sFirstname = "Unknown";
private string m_sLastname = "";
private string m_sGroupCode = "AAA";

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Age is a required field.")]
[Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "A persons age must be between 1 and 100.")]
public int Age
{
    get { return m_iAge; }
    set { m_iAge = value; }
}

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Firstname is a required field.")]
public string Firstname
{
    get { return m_sFirstname; }
    set { m_sFirstname = value; }
}

public string Lastname
{
    get { return m_sLastname; }
    set { m_sLastname = value; }
}

[StringLength(3, MinimumLength = 3)]
public string GroupCode
{
    get { return m_sGroupCode; }
    set { m_sGroupCode = value; }
}

public void Validate() {
    ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(this, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
    List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(this, context, results, true);

    if (isValid == false) {
        StringBuilder sbrErrors = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var validationResult in results) {
            sbrErrors.AppendLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        }
        throw new ValidationException(sbrErrors.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

Back in the code behind of the form, you just need to call the Validate method for each class.

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RequiredFieldsInClassExample {
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        try {
            lstStatus.Items.Clear();
            lstStatus.Items.Add("Creating list of people");
            List<Person> CollectionOfPeople = new List<Person>();

            lstStatus.Items.Add("Creating a good person");
            Person Jeff = new Person();
            Jeff.Age = 33;
            Jeff.Firstname = "Jeff";
            Jeff.Lastname = "Jefferson";
            Jeff.GroupCode = "JJJ";
            // LOOK! This line was added
            Jeff.Validate();

            CollectionOfPeople.Add(Jeff);

            lstStatus.Items.Add("Creating a bad person");
            Person Tim = new Person();
            Tim.Age = 444;
            Tim.Firstname = "";
            Tim.Lastname = "";
            Tim.GroupCode = "";
            // LOOK! This line was added
            Tim.Validate();

            CollectionOfPeople.Add(Tim);

            lstStatus.Items.Add("Done");
        } catch (ValidationException Exp) {
            MessageBox.Show(this, Exp.Message, "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        } catch (Exception Exp) {
            MessageBox.Show(this, Exp.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I've done this in , but I'll give it a shot.  It think you need to manually validate the class using the [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  You can also implement [`IValidatableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) on the class that needs validating - I like this approach.

Comment: I suggest you add a [link to blog post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx) which shows exactly what you're suggesting to do.

Comment: @Michael...Sorry Micheal didn't see your comment until I posted my response. I actually answer questions based on experience and knowledge, not searching for answers.  If you want to post a similar answer to mine, I'll gladly delete my response.  Bottom line is this guy needs help.

Comment: @Big Daddy - Thanks for the help. You helped steer me towards the answer. I appreciate the help! :)

Comment: @BigDaddy no pressure at all, was thinking link to code example may enrich your answer. Apologies if my comment was offensive.

Comment: @ThePeter...Glad to help.  Please mark this as answered/useful if it answered your question.  Thanks.